# How do I prevent a user from logging in from 2 locations at the same time?

Tags: php, security

How do I prevent a user from logging in from 2 locations at the same time?   A username and password can only be used by 1 person at the same time.

Please send me the code in PHP.

Comment: I have to say, it's not often that a "plz-send-the-code" question is identified as such in the body of the question ;-)

Comment: @David Zaslavsky  yeah and he isn't going to get that from SO.  People get paid for that.

Comment: @The Rook: yeah, that part was implied.

Comment: @The Rook:  Why did you remove the "plz-send-the-code"?   That changes the whole character of the question, for me.  I can't be the only one.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!$user->hasOpenSession()) {
 $user->login();
} else {
 $context->forwardToForbidden();
}
```

Comment: next problem is "same request was sent twice in different sessions and the same response was received" how to protect this

Answer (score 1):

Update the users table on login with the the ip address and login time.  Clear the ip on session timeout or if the user logs out.  Check this ip address upon login to make sure its matches up.  Only check `$_SERVER['remote_addr']`,  you don't want to look at x-forwareded-for because that could be *anything*.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a field in the database that keeps track of active sessions. We can give you other pointers, but without more effort and information on your part, it's impossible to provide code.

Comment: i store the session id in the database...
but i get a Security Issues Do not accept externally created session identifiers by IBM Rational AppScan 7.9.0.2..

Comment: I'm not familiar with IBM Rational AppScan or what vulnerability it is focusing on. However, there is no need to store a session ID. If a user is already logged in, a boolean field is enough to register that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with restrictions based on the IP address with which the user logged on is that, in some cases, it could be the same legitimate user from the same machine/browser but with distinct IP addresses.

One case (quite rare I suppose) could be a pool of HTTP proxies that would use distinct IP addresses to make requests to your server (even though the actual user/browser/machine is the same). Another case, which I think we might see more and more, is the case of mobile devices: a mobile device could potentially travel and re-associate with difference access points and networks, therefore jumping from one IP address to another. In this case, you'd have to force your user to log-on again every time. I'm not sure how big this problem is at the moment, but that could be possible for people travelling on trains or similar (depending on how they access their network).

I think a better solution could consist of destroying any other sessions/authentication cookies you have for that user whenever they log on or log out (and perhaps implementing a time-out if they forget to log out).